# How can I work with filenames with spaces in bjam?

Tags: build, bjam, boost-build, build-tools

I need to describe an external library in a Jamfile.  The location of the library is held in an environment variable.

```
set EX_LIB_PATH=C:\Program Files\Ext
```

Here is the snippet from the Jamfile:

--snip--

```
lib extlin : : <file>$(EXT_LIB_PATH)/lib/library.lib ;
```

--spin--

bjam croaks saying that "C:\Program" cannot be found.  What can be done to get the lib rule call in the Jamfile to accept a path with an embedded space?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but for reference, try this:

```
lib extlin : : <file>"$(EXT_LIB_PATH:J=\ )/lib/library.lib" ;
```

Worked for me on Boost.Jam  Version 3.1.10. OS=NT.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting it in quotes?

```
lib extlin : : <file>"$(EXT_LIB_PATH)/lib/library.lib" ;
```

It's a question of when, exactly, bjam expands the variable name, and if something else further down the line has a problem with a filename with spaces.  But I believe this should work.